# Using a interface as a type parameter of generic class with the limitation of "class" in C#

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Why can you use an `interface` as the type parameter of a generic class where the constraint is `class`?

```
interface IB {}
class A<T> where T : class {}
...
A<IB> a; // why is IB allowed here?
```

Either a reference type or a value type can implement an interface, so you shouldn't be able to use an interface as the type parameter, since the interface declaration is not as "strong" as the limitation.

But in the above example it works without a problem. Why is this allowed? Is the actual object implementing the interface being boxed in the process if it is a value type?

Comment: I rewrote the question and added an example to what I *think* was your intended question. If you feel that I violated this completely, do go to the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36664095/revisions) and rollback to any previous revision

Comment: Thanks! I think your revision explains the problem better than my previous version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any variable typed as an interface type is a reference type, if the implementing type is a value type it will be boxed e.g.

```
IConvertible c = 3;
```

will cause the value `3` to be boxed when assigned to `c`.

If you have a generic type `A<T>` and `T` is an interface type, any reference to `T` inside `A` will also be a reference type so the `class` constraint is satisfied.

Comment: Cool! I thought about boxing, but I was not so sure. Could you provide some document related to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

> where T : class
>
> The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, **interface**, delegate, or array type.

What you're probably looking for is the **new()**-constraint:

> where T : new()
>
> The type argument must have a public parameterless constructor. When used together with other constraints, the new() constraint must be specified last.

If you use that

```
class A<B> where B : new()
```

then `IB` cannot be used as a parameter:

> Error CS0310  'IB' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'A'

Comment: That’s not really conveying why you can use an interface as a `class` constrained type argument when the interface can be implemented by a value type.

Comment: @poke - He has certainly conveyed it. He's quoted the docs. It doesn't matter if he interface is implemented by a value-type or not. If the spec says an interface can be used when the generic type is constrained by class then it just doesn't matter what the underlying type is.

Comment: @poke well, I'd say it's simply possible because the semantics of the type system allow it. See it in conjunction with [@Lee's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36664207/594832). Since a value type is boxed, it conforms to the constraint. Hence the advice to use the `new()`-constraint.

Comment: @khlr - It's doesn't matter if it is boxed. The documentation says that an `interface` (no matter what it is) conforms to the `class` constraint. You don't need worry about what type it is, it just works because it conforms to the documentation.

Comment: I think Lee's answer solved my problem quite nicely, but your discussion about the "new" constraint is very inspiring, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All I can suggest is that you read the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx). It states for a constraint of `class` that:

> The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.